# A martingale related proof, need help

Tags: martingales, local-martingales

could anyone help me with this one line proof?

I couldn't understand the proof in Chapter 1, 4.50 proposition, part(c)，'only if' direction (page53) in Jean Jacod and AN. Shiryear's [Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540439325).

The line I got confused is the equation on top of page 54: how to see the following relation holds:

$\sup_t E[X_t^2] = \sup_t\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\uparrow E[X_{(t\wedge\tau_n)}^2]$.

Here $X$ is a local martingale, and $\tau_n$ is the localizing sequence for the local martingale $X^2 - X_0^2 - [X,X]$. For the 'only if' direction, it is also assumed that $[X,X]\in\mathcal{A}$, i.e $E([X,X]_\infty) < \infty$ and $X_0\in L^2$.

I was trying to convince myself $E[X_t^2] = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\uparrow E[X_{(t\wedge\tau_n)^2}]$. I do know $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} X^2_{t\wedge\tau_n} = X_t^2$ a.s, and $\{Y_n:= X_{t\wedge\tau_n}, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a martingale, hence $Y_n^2 = X^2_{t\wedge\tau_n}$ is a submartingale, and this makes righthand of the above equation as the limit of an increasing sequence. But I don't see the monotonicity of the sequence $X^2_{t\wedge\tau_n}$, nor a dominating random variable for it. So why the switch order of the limit and the expectation hold? I suppose this is some martingale inequality that I don't know?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Erm... so you see an increasing sequence (a consequence of the submartingale property, indeed), but no monotonicity?! And if it's monotone, there will be a limit, finite or infinite. That's possibly investigated in the part of the proof you didn't show us.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but ... when I try to apply the monotone convergence theorem,  the monotonicity I refer to is, almost surely, the sequence $X^2_{t\wedge\tau_n}$ is increasing, and this is what I do not see. The sub martingale property only gives the increasing of $E(X^2_{t\wedge\tau_n})$?

Comment: Oops... no, it isn't increasing in that sense. I'm sorry, I forget that those things aren't exactly general knowledge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_convergence_theorems

Comment: Any hint why Doob martingale convergence theorem relevant here?

Comment: As far as I can see, the authors assume that $[X,X]$ has integrable variation? I cannot find this assumption in your question here. Can you please clarify? Thanks,

Comment: Sorry about that, I updated my post just now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{E}[X,X]_{\infty}<\infty$ and $[X,X]_t$ is non-decreasing (in $t$), we have $\mathbb{E}[X,X]_t < \infty$ for each $t \geq 0$. Applying Doob's maximal inequality we find that

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{s \leq t \wedge \tau_n} X_s^2 \right) \leq 4 \mathbb{E}(X_{t \wedge \tau_n}^2) = 4 (\mathbb{E}(X_0^2)+\mathbb{E}[X,X]_{t \wedge \tau_n}).$$

By monotonicity, $\mathbb{E}[X,X]_{t \wedge \tau_n} \leq \mathbb{E}[X,X]_t<\infty$, and so

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{s \leq t \wedge \tau_n} X_s^2 \right) \leq 4 (\mathbb{E}(X_0^2)+\mathbb{E}(X_t^2)).$$

It follows from the monotone convergence theorem that

$$\mathbb{E}\left( \sup_{s \leq t} X_s^2 \right) \leq  4 (\mathbb{E}(X_0^2)+\mathbb{E}(X_t^2))< \infty.$$

In particular, $\sup_{s \leq t} X_s^2$ is an integrable dominating function for $X_{t \wedge \tau_n}^2$. Since $X_{t \wedge \tau_n} \to X_t$ almost surely, the dominated convergence theorem gives

$$\mathbb{E}(X_t^2) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(X_{t \wedge \tau_n}^2).$$

Comment: Thank you for your post! Please excuse me, as I still lost a point here: since $X$ is a local martingale,  I think I can apply the Doob maximal inequality to the martingale $\{X_{s\wedge\tau_n}, s\leq t\}$, and this yield that $E[\sup_{s\leq \tau_n} X^2_s]\leq 4E[X^2_{t\wedge\tau_n}]$. How could we yield that $\sup_{s\leq t} X^2_s$ is square integrable?

Comment: @Robert You are right, we cannot apply Doob's maximal inequality this way. I fixed the proof, using the assumption which you forgot to mention.

Comment: This is very clear, thank you so much! @saz

Comment: @Robert You are welcome.